# Javascript form wont scroll to top on next step

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling with multi-step form written in JS. I am still learning a lot, and I found on W3SCHOOL a nice example of multistep form. When you add more "items" on the first and second step of the form and click that next button while you are on the first step of the form you end up in the middle of the second step of the form...

Here is [that W3 tutorial and code.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps)

What should I write and where in that code to make it always go to the top of the "page"? Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To make something always go to the top of the page, use the `#` in the link:

```
<a href="#">Go to top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I've given two examples to scroll to top of the page.

1. Without animation and without any script
   Scroll Top

   **Note:** Here if you replace # with some specific section or div Ids like #form-section etc., then when you click on this link it will scroll to that section.
2. With animation - Using script and CSS(Suggested)

   **Note:** This example you can use anywhere even for websites as well to scroll to top of the page

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="scrollToTop">
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span> <!-- Here you can use any arrow icon or plain as well based on that make changes in CSS. Here for sample I've given font awesome icon -->
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
    .scrollToTop {
        z-index: 999;
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 30px;
        left: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
<pre>
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    }else{
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});
</pre>
```